# MacBook Air won't power on, unless battery disconnected and plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power, power-management

This is for those who have had trouble with all the combined issues:

- Macbook Air 2012-2017 ( possibly other models)
- Won't turn on unless the battery is disconnected for a short time and then plugged in.
- Connecting the mag-safe cord is what only turns it on.
- Tried SMC reset Tried PRAM/NVRAM
- Tried a different battery
- Battery still charges.
- Ready to sell it for parts due to a total waste of precious time!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that I only discovered in the process. I was not able to find this while researching so I hope it serves your success!

My solution: Disconnect all cables to the motherboard (flex cables, plug-ins etc). Let it sit for an extended period of time (I left it overnight). Reconnect everything, but the key thing is to CONNECT THE BATTERY LAST. Now try and turn it on. This worked for me twice because I accidentally got it stuck back to the original issue, and found out this solution when I backtracked to find out what fixed the problem.

My assumption is that there must be a sitting charge somewhere in the motherboard that causes the power-on issue. Once it dissipated, then the MacBook functions back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Having had this problem recently and finding no answers I set about looking for internal power problems.
There is one very obvious one, the keyboard!!
Upon removing the battery again! I found the connector at the keyboard itself had corrosion on it. Cleaned and reconnected evrything, TADA!!!
It all works now.
Good luck to anyone withe same problem, try the keyboard cable first, wish I had :(